# jQuery UI Tooltip Being Layered

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

There is UI Jquery Tooltip plugin. We have code:

```
  $(function() {$( document ).tooltip({ 
    position: {my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center'},
    show: 400,
    hide: 400,
    items: 'teacher',
    content: 'connecting',
    content: function(callback) {
            var x=$(this).attr('teacher-id') 
            $.get('teacher_ajax.php?teacherid='+x,{}, function(data)
            {
            callback(data);
        });
    }, 
  })}
  );
```

And elements in HTML:

```
<teacher teacher-id="1">First teacher</teacher>
<teacher teacher-id="2">Second teacher</teacher>
<teacher teacher-id="3">Third teacher</teacher>
```

Everything seems to work fine ([demo](http://www.sundayrock.ru/schedule/tooltip.php)), but tips are being layered on each other, so is there any method to prevent it? I think the most nice way is to execute only one script at a time, maybe it will fix the problem?
Something like this?

```
$(document).mouseout(function(){$( document ).tooltip({close});});
```

Comment: Almost same problem described here http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9198

Comment: Well it seems like there is some problem in library, so for now it is more suitable to use any other way. I found [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) very helpful and made everything i need